# Unexpected translateZ behavior with Framer Motion

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to place some elements as if they were wrapped around a circle and I am getting some unexpected behavior applying a translateZ to my elements with framer motion.

If I apply the styles with a template literal, not using framer motion's shorthand for transforms, I get the intended effect, like this:

```
transform: `
  rotateY(${
    i * (360 / images.length) <= 180 ? 
    i * (360 / images.length) : 
    ((i - (images.length)) * (360 / images.length))
  }deg) 
  translateZ(300px)
`
```

But if I apply them with the framer motion shorthand I get a different result, like this:

```
rotateY: 
  i * (360 / images.length) <= 180 ?
  i * (360 / images.length) : 
  ((i - (images.length)) * (360 / images.length)),
translateZ: '300px',
```

Also, if I apply just a rotateY using framer motion's shorthand, it adds a translateZ(0px) too. If you try to set your own translateZ, it will render both styles inline like this:

```
translateZ(300px) rotateY(-45deg) translateZ(0px);
```

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-unexpected-translate-z-behavior-cj891l?file=/src/App.js). You can try commenting in 1 of the 2 blocks of transform styles to see the different results.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to set translateZ as z prop, as is shown in this fork of your code, in that example, it sets correctly only once the translateZ transform

https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-unexpected-translate-z-behavior-forked-y44wps?file=/src/App.js

But to get your effect work, first must be applied rotation and then transform, as order of definition is important in trasnform property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#transform_order

I think is a framer motion issue, they have setted specific order to transformations:

https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/ea955e0f22971f6c6cb3784b47e8a709dc53bdd4/packages/framer-motion/src/render/html/utils/transform.ts#L11

So, I think you can use framer motion properties, but figure out how to replicate the same effect but using the framer motion transform order